# MVC Razor RadioButtonFor in ForEach loop

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to MVC. I am trying to render questions with options using radio buttons.
Here is what I have tried. I am able to display questions with options using radio buttons, but I can select only one radio button across the questions.

Model:

```
public class CheckListModel()
{
    IEnumerable<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set; }    
}

Public class QuestionModel()
{
    Int Id { get; set; }
    string Question { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<AnswerModel> Answers { get; set; }
}

Public class AnswerModel()
{
    Int Id { get; set; }
    string Answer { get; set; } 
}
```

View:

```
@if (Model != null)
{
  if (Model.CheckListModel != null)
  {
    int i = 0;
    <div class="form-group">
      <fieldset>
      @foreach (var question in Model.CheckListModel.Questions)
      {
        <legend>@question.Question</legend>
        foreach (var answer in question.Answers)
        {
          i++;
          string nameAtt = "Grp" + i.ToString();
          <div class="radio">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(a => a.eCheckListModel.Questions.Where( q => q.Id == 
              question.Id).FirstOrDefault().Answers.Where(b => b.Id == answer.Id).FirstOrDefault
              ().Answer, answer.Id.ToString(), new { @name = nameAtt, @id = nameAtt })
            @answer.Answer
          </div>
        } 
      }
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: For each question, you are rendering a series of radio buttons. Are you saying you want to be able select one radio button within each question group? If you are currently only any able to select one on the whole page then its because the values of the name attributes are all the same

Comment: Using `@name = nameAtt` is pointless. Html helper methods ignore any attempt to set the name attribute (for very good reason - they generate the proper name for postback)

Comment: Thanks for replying Stephen, Can you give me an example. I am using @HtmlRadioButtonFor coz i want it to be a strongly typed.

Comment: First thing you need to do is get rid of this horrific use of Linq queries within the view and populate your model in the controller. Second, you need a property in `QuestionModel` that you can bind the selected answer to.  Before I give an example, can you confirm what you want to post back - I assume you need a collection of Questions that contains the ID of the Question and the ID of the selected Answer

Comment: Yes correct i need to send back a collection of Questions that contains the ID of the Question and the ID of the selected Answer

Comment: I've added an answer with an example of how you can do this. You seem to have another top level model that contained property `CheckListModel` (but you didn't post it) so my example is based on the model in the view being ``CheckListModel`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach wont work because the name attribute of each radio button is not being renered correctly. Using `... new { @name = nameAtt,..` is pointless because Html Helpers override any attempt to set the name attribute.

Firstly, populate your view models in the controller (populate each question with the answers relevant to that question) and add a property to the `QuestionModel` that allows you to bind the selected answer.

Models

```
public class CheckListModel
{
  public List<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set; } // use List (easier for indexing the name attribute
  ... // other properties of model
}

public class QuestionModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Question { get; set; }
  public int SelectedAnswer { get; set; } // Add this
  public List<AnswerModel> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class AnswerModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model YourAssembly.CheckListModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Questions[i].ID) // for postback
    <p>@Model.Questions[i].Question</p>
    for (int j = 0; j < Model.Questions[i].Answers.Count; j++)
    {
      <div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Questions[i].SelectedAnswer, Model.Questions[i].Answers[j].ID)
        <span>@Model.Questions[i].Answers[j].Answer</span>
      </div>   
    }
  }
  ....
}
```

This will render inputs `<input type="hidden" name="Questions[0].ID"..`, `<input type="radio" name="Questions[0].SelectedAnswer"..` etc

Comment: Thanks a lot, stephen. The above solution worked for me.

Comment: Why is SelectedAnswer an integer and not a boolean?

Comment: @Elisa, There can be multiple answers for a question defined by `List<AnswerModel>` and `AnswerModel` has property `int ID`. There are no boolean properties. It needs to be `int` so the ID of the selected answer an be determined when you post back.